# max-width and float divs

Tags: html, css

what i have is 3 divs, 1 for left 1 for center and 1 for right
what i need is 3 columns - the left is always there, the center as well but it's width should be adaptive if the right is there or not

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:460px; padding:0px 20px;">
        <div style="float:left; background: red; width:100px;">
            red
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; background: yellow;  max-width:400px">
            yellow
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; background: green; width:100px;">
            green
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

what am i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You realise that the div with the content `left left...` is actually on the right? ([JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VZ7aL/)).

Comment: i know - i just made a quick example cause i want to learn that thing once and for all... you can answer me and replace the border with background color

Comment: My point is, effectively, that apart from the `...middle...` column, I've got no idea which side the other two are meant to be on? Does the HTML have to remain as-is, can it be adapted?

Comment: the main div has a fixed width, in that example 500px. the others are 100, 300, 100. the third one (green) can be there or not. if green is not there, yellow should be 400px

Comment: one thing you are not considering is that the edges of the "divs" will also take up space. So here you have to add 2px more for each "div".
container: 500px
contents: 506px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could come up with, in order to avoid JavaScript solutions and to use CSS and HTML only, is to use class-names for the columns, and to re-order your HTML in order that the right-most column is first in the html:

```
<div class="wrap" style="width:500px">
    <div class="col right">Right Column</div>
    <div class="col left">Left column</div>
    <div class="col middle">Middle column</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap" style="width:500px">
    <div class="col left">Left column 2</div>
    <div class="col middle">Middle column 2</div>
</div>​
```

With the CSS adjacent-sibling selector, `firstSibling + secondSibling`, this can be used to amend the width of the middle column:

```
.wrap {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left,
.right {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #ffa;
}

.middle {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #f90;
}

.left,
.middle {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

div.right + div.left + div.middle {
    width: 300px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VZ7aL/1/).

If you float the `.middle` column *right*, instead of *left* as in the previous example, then you can simplify the adjacent-sibling selector, and the HTML is, effectively, visually reversed (which is slightly easier to understand/work with than the above example wherein the two columns come first, in reverse order, and then the middle column comes at the end), giving:

```
<div class="wrap" style="width:500px">
    <div class="col right">Right Column</div>
    <div class="col middle">Middle column</div>
    <div class="col left">Left column</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap" style="width:500px">
    <div class="col left">Left column 2</div>
    <div class="col middle">Middle column 2</div>
</div>​
```

And the CSS:

```
.wrap {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left,
.right {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #ffa;
}

.middle {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #f90;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right,
.middle {
    float: right;
}

div.right + div.middle {
    width: 300px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VZ7aL/2/).

References:

- [Adjacent sibling selector, at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

Comment: I end up doing this - thank you for the  Adjacent sibling - i never used it before - it work like a charm ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Width includes borders, you have to take that into consideration.  If you decrease the width of the center element a bit, the right will not wrap.

I don't however see anything in your code which would handle the center width being "adaptive".

Comment: i know - i just made a quick example cause i want to learn that thing once and for all... you can answer me and replace the border with background color

Comment: Well then what is the actual problem and what is the actual code?  Is it the "adaptive" part, and if so, what have you tried to make it adaptive?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but this might work.  If you can give a little more detail about what it is supposed to do, it would help, but this seems to do what you want.  If the right column is set to display:none then the center still goes all the way over.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:480px; padding:0px 20px;">
    <div style="float:left; background: red; width:100px;">
        red
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; background: green; width:100px;>
        green
    </div>
    <div style="background: yellow; width:100%;">
        yellow
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```